Is the shear stiffness of a helical spring for bending negligible?
I want to model a helical spring by beam theory. Lets call $d$ the stock wire diameter and $D=2r$ the the helix radius (see picture below).

For example: The axial stretch stiffness is given as here. I can calculate the axial displacement as $\Delta l_{axial}=\frac{PL}{(EA)}=\frac{PL8nD^3}{Gd^4}$, where $P$ is some axial force, $n$ are the number of coils, $L$ is the total length and $G$ the shear modulus of the stock wire. Note that I replaced the ordinary axial stiffness by one that is correct for the helical spring.
Similarly you can derive bending stiffness and a torsional stiffness.
What I'm currently stuck with is the shear stiffness. For a ordinary beam this behaves as in the picture below

Applying the force $P$ will cause compression at the top and extension at the bottom. Now when doing the same for a spring we get the following picture:

Up until a point of critical curvature the inner coil segments will not touch. Therefore I somehow have the feeling that since there is no resistance to the compression or extension (if the coils don't touch) in the bending plane the shear should vanish.
My Questions:
Is this intuition correct, that the shear stiffness in this case is negligible or even vanishes?
If not, what would be the actual shear stiffness I can use in my beam model of the spring?

Related How is it that on loading a spring, shearing stress is produced?. There is an old textbook, The General Properties of Matter by Newman & Searle, which you may find interesting? 64 Sprial springs p111
